# manually ValueChanged on numericupdown

Tags: vb.net

I tried these three Handler and now I can get back the error to valuechange, or KeyPress (for example, by pressing enter). 
With the KeyPress event the sub is called once for control; In fact, if unleashed carried to the error in the first control and then after working on other return on the same; the second time does not call the sub 
The second problem is when I try to trigger this error moving from an 'other using the mouse.

```
Sub () ...
AddHandler advacedNumeric.ValueChanged, AddressOf ValueChanged
    AddHandler advacedNumeric.MouseEnter, AddressOf ValueChanged
    AddHandler advacedNumeric.KeyPress, AddressOf ValueChanged
End Sub ...

Public Sub SetError(ByVal numeric As UtAdvancedNumeric, ByVal errorDescription As     String)
    mErrorProvider.Clear()
    mErrorProvider.BlinkStyle = ErrorBlinkStyle.NeverBlink
    mErrorProvider.SetIconAlignment(numeric, ErrorIconAlignment.MiddleRight)
    mErrorProvider.SetError(numeric, errorDescription)
End Sub

Public Sub ValueChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
Dim advancedNumeric As New UtAdvancedNumeric
    advancedNumeric = sender
    mErrorProvider.Clear()
    Dim value As Double = 0
    Try
        value = advancedNumeric.ActiveControl.Text
    Catch
        value = 0
    End Try

    Dim min As Double = advancedNumeric.MinValue
    If value < min Then
        SetError(advancedNumeric, "Valore inferiore al minimo consentito di : " & min & "")
        advancedNumeric.Value = min
    End If
    Dim max As Double = advancedNumeric.MaxValue
    If value > max Then
        SetError(advancedNumeric, "Valore superiore al minimo consentito di : " & max & "")
        advancedNumeric.Value = max
    End If
   End Sub
```

UtAdvancedNumeric is a custom control based on numericUpDown.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Your Handlers are spelled "advacedNumeric"... is this the name you gave that control or accidental typo? I ask because you create a new variable called "advancedNumeric" in the ValueChanged function.

Comment: I cant quite tell what the question is, but since you do `mErrorProvider.Clear()` in `ValueChanged`, myUpDn2 will erase myUpDn1's errors.  you'll only retain 1 error at most only when the last control has an error. `value = advancedNumeric.ActiveControl.Text` is iffy as it includes an implicit conversion (use Option Strict).  Finally, the standard UpDn, fixes any out of range value typed in when the control looses focus, so any errors you do set are automatically fixed and the error messages are wrong.

Comment: my goal is to avoid the automatic correction by the system , and also trigger this error moving from one advancedControl to another using the mouse.

Comment: Is this a subclassed control, or are you trying to just add some code to a form to change what it does?  The way it you have it, the mouse passing over a control will clear all the accumulated errors.   Just monitor the Leave Event and fix it so each ValueChanged event doesnt clear all the errors so far.

Comment: 1) `my goal is to avoid the automatic correction by the system` not with that code you wont - you explicitly set `.Value` to `.Min` or `.Max` if it fails just after the call to `SetError` thereby correcting the error  2) to check the value when moving to another control, use the Leave event.  But each time you do catch an out of range value, you are clearing all the previous errors in `SetError` with `mErrorProvider.Clear()`

Comment: How can I improve the code ? In my opinion this work well ... but I'm a noob , and I accept any advice.if I enter a correct value in the control with the error icon, how do I remove the icon?  There is any method to cancel error icon ? Thnaks